# Pandas group rows by 1 second interval then find the highest/lowest/earliest/last value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame read from a csv file. something like this:

| TIMESTAMP | PRICE |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 09:30:00.005037 | 151.405000 |
| 2022-08-01 09:30:00.005038 | 155.405000 |
| 2022-08-01 09:30:00.005040 | 153.405000 |
| 2022-08-01 09:31:00.005000 | 161.405000 |
| 2022-08-01 09:31:00.006038 | 165.405000 |
| 2022-08-01 09:31:00.007038 | 163.405000 |

The desiable result is to group by 1 second, and find the lowest higest and earliest and last values

| TIMESTAMP | LOWEST_PRICE | HIGHEST_PRICE | EARLIEST_PRICE | LAST_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 09:30:00.000000 | 151.405000 | 155.405000 | 151.405000 | 153.405000 |
| 2022-08-01 09:31:00.000000 | 161.405000 | 165.405000 | 161.405000 | 163.405000 |

I have used:

```
df.resample('1S').agg(['min','max', 'first', 'last'])
```

but I am keep getting index error, and I don't know how to add a new colounm into the data frame.
could it be possible through a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html#pandas-grouper) object and managing column index:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='TIMESTAMP', freq='1S')).agg(['min','max', 'first', 'last'])\
    .dropna().droplevel(0, axis=1)\
    .rename(columns={'min': 'LOWEST_PRICE','max': 'HIGHEST_PRICE',
                     'first': 'EARLIEST_PRICE', 'last':'LAST_PRICE'}).reset_index()

print(df)
```

The output:

```
            TIMESTAMP  LOWEST_PRICE  HIGHEST_PRICE  EARLIEST_PRICE  LAST_PRICE
0 2022-08-01 09:30:00       151.405        155.405         151.405     153.405
1 2022-08-01 09:31:00       161.405        165.405         161.405     163.405
```

Comment: what if there is a extra column called BID, and I want have max min last first of bid as LOWEST_BID, HIGHEST_BID, EARLIST_BID, LAST_BID along side with the four columns you answered.